# Template functions by index in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

Suppose I have a class in C++11 like this:

```
class Something
{
...
private:
   class1* a;
   class2* b;
   class3* c;

public:

   class1* reada() { return a; }
   class2* readb() { return b; }
   class3* readc() { return c; }

   void customFunctionForclass1();
   void customFunctionForclass2();
   void customFunctionForclass3();
}


}
```

I'd like to make the read functions templated so that if another programmer adds another member class, the corresponding read function will be template-magic created.

Something like this maybe?

```
class Something
{
...
private:

   templateContainer = {class1*,class2*,class3*}

   template<thing in templateContainer>
   thing variableOfTypeThing;

public:

   template<thing in templateContainer>
   <thing> read() {return variableOfTypeThing<thing>;}

   void customFunctionForclass1();
   void customFunctionForclass2();
   void customFunctionForclass3();
}
```

As you can tell from the example, I'm confused.

Basically, I have a class which acts as a container for guaranteed unique class variables (no class1 A; class1 B)
Some function groups for the class are almost identical some function groups are highly varied. It would be great for future people to only have to modify the different parts of the class and get the rest from the templates.

I thought maybe there would be a way by splitting this class up into lots of classes and stuffing them into an array of void pointers, but that seems unwise.

Suggestions?

Comment: C++ does not work this way. You will probably have to implement this class itself as a template with a variadic parameter pack, use it to declare a `std::tuple` of all the pointers, and then maybe a template read function, to access the tuple. That's probably the simplest way to get the basic semantics right.

Comment: One `Something` contains one pointer, or one of each type as in the first snippet?

Comment: Beside your question there is also the problem that a,b,c are private members and must not be exposed outside of the class instance. A prototype of a reada() should at worst be const class1 * reada(); otherwise you break the encapsulation principle

Comment: While `std::tuple` should be a good start (as suggested), what is the purpose of doing such design? What are you trying to do? It might be possible that another solution might be more appropriate or that our answer don't really fill all your needs. Some other things of interest are **visitors**, `std::variant` and `std::function` and maybe traditional object-oriented design might be more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, the software I'm working in has maybe 30 COM interfaces which every class requests using requestInterface chains. I'd like to make these interfaces global, but only allow the ModuleMgr (This is basically the entry point of the dll) to initialize the pointers to quarantine weird bugs to one spot.

Comment: K, I managed to implement it. Thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to make the read functions templated so that if another programmer adds another member class, the corresponding read function will be template-magic created.

You could encapsulate the user defined classes in a thin wrapper class with a `read()` function that returns the contained instance. Adding a user defined class to `Something` would then be done by inheriting `wrapper<user_defined_class>`.

> Basically, I have a class which acts as a container for guaranteed unique class variables

Inheriting this wrapper prevents you from including the same class twice so it could possibly be a way forward:

```
#include <iostream>

// the "thing" wrapper
template<typename T>
struct thing {

    // forward construction arguments to the contained variable
    template<class... Args>
    thing(Args&&... args) : variable(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}

    // basic interface, const and non-const. I called it get() instead of read()
    T const& get() const { return variable; }
    T& get() { return variable; }

private:
    T variable;
};

// a troublesome user defined class that is not default constructibe :-(
struct user_defined {
    user_defined() = delete; // silly example really, but it's just to demonstrate

    user_defined(const std::string& v) : str(v) {}
    user_defined& operator=(const std::string& v) {
        str = v;
        return *this;
    }
    std::string const& say() const { return str; }

private:
    std::string str;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const user_defined& ud) {
    return os << ud.say();
}

// ... and the "Something" class that inherits the wrapped types.
class Something : thing<int>,
                  thing<double>,
                  thing<user_defined> 
{
public:
    // add initial values for types that are not default constructible
    Something(const std::string& val) : thing<user_defined>(val) {}
    Something() : Something("") {} // default ctor

    // access via derived class, const and non-const
    template<typename T>
    T const& get() const {
        return thing<T>::get(); // get() from the correct base
    }
    template<typename T>
    T& get() {
        return thing<T>::get(); // get() from the correct base
    }
};

void print(const Something& s) {
    // using the const interface
    std::cout << s.get<int>() << "\n";
    std::cout << s.get<double>() << "\n";
    std::cout << s.get<user_defined>() << "\n";
}

int main() {
    Something foo;

    // using the non-const interface to set
    foo.get<int>() = 10;
    foo.get<double>() = 3.14159;
    foo.get<user_defined>() = "Hello world";

    print(foo);
}
```

Edit: It doesn't fulfill the *index* part of your question though. You access it using the type you'd like to `get()` as a tag. You basically build a very rudimentary tuple I guess.

Comment: One could add another wrapper `template<class ...args> things: thing<args>... {...};` which forwards the `get`s as you did. Then `Something` could inherit (`public`ally) from `things<int, double, user_defined>`. This is less to write and one does not have to forward the get functions in `Something`.

Comment: @n314159 Yes, that sounds even better and makes it even more tuple-like. In such a wrapper, if most, but not all, contained types are default constructible one would have to value-initialize all of them I guess?

Comment: Yes, you probably have to. I am unsure if one can expose the constructors of the `thing` through `things` such that one could write something like `Something(string val, int i): thing<i>(i), thing<user_defined>(val) {}`.

Comment: @n314159 sounds like a nicer exercise to try out though. I haven't used tuples much but if it can't be done with them it's probably hard.

Comment: I implemented it (see other answer). In the end it was not that hard, but one has to expose both classes for construction (I had hoped that only one of them could be visible to the user). I tried much more complicted things, but this seems best.

Answer (score 1):

Code based on @Ted Lyngmo's answer:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<typename T>
struct thing {

    // forward construction arguments to the contained variable

    template<class... Args>
    thing(Args&&... args) : variable(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}

    // basic interface, const and non-const. I called it get() instead of read()
    T const& get() const { return variable; }
    T& get() { return variable; }

protected:
    T variable;
};


template<typename ...Ts>
struct things : thing<Ts>... {

    template<class... SubTs>
    things(thing<SubTs>&&... ts) : thing<SubTs>(std::move(ts))... {}

    // access via derived class, const and non-const
    template<typename T>
    T const& get() const {
        return thing<T>::get(); // get() from the correct base
    }
    template<typename T>
    T& get() {
        return thing<T>::get(); // get() from the correct base
    }
};


// a troublesome user defined class that is not default constructibe :-(
struct user_defined {
    user_defined() = delete; // silly example really, but it's just to demonstrate

    user_defined(const std::string& v) : str(v) {}
    user_defined& operator=(const std::string& v) {
        str = v;
        return *this;
    }
    std::string const& say() const { return str; }

private:
    std::string str;
};

struct non_default {
    non_default() = delete;

    non_default(int) {}
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const user_defined& ud) {
    return os << ud.say();
}

// ... and the "Something" class that inherits the wrapped types.
class Something : public things<int, double, user_defined, non_default>
{
public:
    // add initial values for types that are not default constructible
    Something(const std::string& val) : things(thing<user_defined>(val), thing<non_default>(0)) {}
    Something() : Something("") {} // default ctor

};

void print(const Something& s) {
    // using the const interface
    std::cout << s.get<int>() << "\n";
    std::cout << s.get<double>() << "\n";
    std::cout << s.get<user_defined>() << "\n";
}

int main() {
    Something foo;

    // using the non-const interface to set
    foo.get<int>() = 10;
    foo.get<double>() = 3.14159;
    foo.get<user_defined>() = "Hello world";

    print(foo);
}
```